# How to allow type conversions in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, type-conversion, compiler-construction

I'm working with an old C++ application that has been certified for a certain system.  So, I'm not allowed to make any changes.  However, I have to make a new build in Visual Studio 2019. I am running into a lot of conversions issues like this.

```
void sendMsg(char* msg)
{
    // code
}

int main()
{
    sendMsg("hello");
}
```

> [Error (active) E0167 argument of type "const char" is incompatible with parameter of type "char".]

Is there a setting in Visual Studio I can use to allow these types of conversions to happen?

Comment: Change `void sendMsg(char* msg)` to `void sendMsg(const char* msg)`, that's it.

Comment: `/permissive`. But the reason doesn't make sense. Change compiler completely voids any certification. You wouldn't get same code if it's not portable . And this code NEVER was legal in C++, so it's not portable.

Comment: This is not _"implicit conversion"_ it's an attempt at an illegal conversion. MSVC use to allow this but is now more Standard's compliant. Have a look at [/Zc:strictStrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-strictstrings-disable-string-literal-type-conversion?view=msvc-170) __but__ please just fix the code.

Comment: *So, I'm not allowed to make any changes. However, I have to make a new build in Visual Studio 2019* -- To be honest, it was unrealistic to think that *no* changes would have to be made, given that you are using a newer compiler, newer C++ standards, etc.  Who made that decision to not make any changes?  It probably was not a C++ programmer.

Comment: If you are changing compiler version and/or compiler flags this is just as impactful (or more impactful) on certification as changing the source code.  Check with your certification team to ensure that these changes are allowed.  When I was last producing certified builds, the entire tool-chain and source code were frozen and __any__ changes needed an impact evaluation.  Changing compiler version would probably require re-certification of the product.

Comment: I think the downvotes are a little mean.  It's not the OP's fault that he has been given an impossible assignment.

Comment: @PaulSanders I didn't downvote, but the downvote reasons contain unhelpful question. The title is wrong. It's not an implicit conversion. IMO this question should be improved and is currently bad.

Comment: @jabaa And it's not the OP's fault that he is inexperienced.  If you (or anybody else) find the title misleading, just edit it.

Comment: @OP -- Another thing is let's say you got the program to build with no changes.  Then it is discovered that the new build exposed a bug, and you now have no choice but to change the code to fix the bug.  What do you do then?  Many times, newer compilers will reveal runtime bugs that you never knew existed in the original program.  I would have expected a company that uses certified programs to have a sandbox test area, just to see what happens when a newer compiler is used, so as to evaluate what may need to be done.  The hard rule of "no coding changes" again, was unrealistic.

Comment: What was used to build it before?  Any reason not to stick with that, all the old versions of VS are available on MSDN?

Comment: @PaulSanders -- Where I used to work, it was a requirement to use tools that were not out-of-date or out-of-support to build the applications.  Maybe that's the situation that the OP is in, but was given unrealistic requirements.

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm voting good and bad questions similar like I would vote good and bad Wikipedia articles or blog posts. Good questions are complete, readable and understandable. The title of this question was wrong. Multiple users mentioned it in the comments. The OP can improve the question. With the wrong title the question isn't really helpful for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Swift!  Using /permissive worked like a charm.

I probably should have given a few more details.

1. As I said, I don't have the option of changing the code.
2. I have to get it built in Visual Studio 2019.
3. The original code was written for a much older version of C++

The points that I did not mention before were:

1. This was a complete and functioning Linux application.

   a) Since the application was complete, no new development
   was going to happen.  Therefore, I did not care about
   error checking.
2. I needed to build a Windows version of the application in VS.
3. The code base contained thousands of files.  Changing all of them
   would have exceeded my time budget.
4. There may be a new version of the Linux build.  I did not want
   to introduce possible issues with a code base that was previously
   stable.  I also didn't want to maintain two code bases.

Comment: Read my comment in the main section about possibly finding bugs with the build you now have.

Comment: `/permissive` turns off __a lot__ of Standard Conforming behaviour, see my comment above for a option that just addresses this one issue.